# php auto-replace link css

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have MVC structure where I load view. In view I use BASE_URL constant to adjust CSS and JS links to my defined folder. I want to remove BASE_URL from links but still loading files from that path.

My template folder path: `http://website.com/project/template/default/`

```
$template = 'default';

BASE_PATH = 'website.com/project/';
```

in my **view**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>template/default/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

**My goal:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

**Question:**

How to achieve that ? Looking for ideas / suggestions / code.

*Note: I don't want to move my template folder.*

Thank you.

**My idea:**

I am thinking about Javascript replacing when view loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some thing like this(using jquery):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" class="my_link" />

$('my_link').attr('href', 'your_href');
```

Comment: This is just _"surface makeup"_. When I open source code I still see real path.